# Why Spring taking too much time to load Dozer instance?

Tags: java, spring, mapping, javabeans, dozer

I am using [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html)  to map java bean to java bean.
Creating Dozer instance with spring injection but seems some thing wrong when I am specifying absolute path of mapping files.

Here is snap of how I am defining it in spring config file :

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
  <property name="mappingFiles">
    <list>
        <value>file:C:/XXX/XXXXXX/dsdsd/dasdas/resosdfsdfurces/dozfsdfsder/agreement_account_mapping.xml</value>

   </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and here is the initialization time logs :

```
2017-02-07 10:57:58,026 INFO  [DozerBeanMapper:175]: Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-02-07 11:19:00,785 INFO  [DozerBeanMapper:222]: Using the following xml files to load custom mappings for the bean mapper instance: [file:C:/GCDB/GCDB_Integration/src/main/resources/dozer/agreement_account_mapping.xml]
2017-02-07 11:19:00,786 INFO  [DozerBeanMapper:224]: Trying to find xml mapping file: file:C:/GCDB/GCDB_Integration/src/main/resources/dozer/agreement_account_mapping.xml
2017-02-07 11:19:00,788 INFO  [DozerBeanMapper:226]: Using URL [file:C:/GCDB/GCDB_Integration/src/main/resources/dozer/agreement_account_mapping.xml] to load custom xml mappings
2017-02-07 11:19:00,807 INFO  [DozerBeanMapper:228]: Successfully loaded custom xml mappings from URL: [file:C:/GCDB/GCDB_Integration/src/main/resources/dozer/agreement_account_mapping.xml]
```

You can observe it taken almost 22 minutes to load.

Any thing wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Also one more thing I observed , its not happening frequently but frequency will be like 5 out of 10.

Comment: Are you able to get anything on this issue? I am having the same concern with Dozer.

Comment: @gjosh No clue, I removed dozzer mapping.